# newton raphson method in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to solve one equation in Matlab with two unknown variables using the Newton raphson method.

The equation is 
I(:,:,K) = IL(:,:,K)-Io(:,:,K)*(exp((V+I*Rs)/a(:,:,K))-1)-((V+I*Rs(:,:,K))/Rsh(:,:,K));

Can this be done in matlab and if so please guide me since I have not managed to find anything related to this equation form!

Thanks

Comment: It can be done in Matlab. Is this homework? And what have you tried? Newton-Raphston is independent of the "equation form", so try implement the algorithm first, edit your question with your attempt, and then we can help you to tweak it.

Comment: I say matlab since this is the programming language I am using! Nothing to do with h/w.

Comment: tbh I have no idea where to start! - I do understand from reading the literature that the newton raphson is the technique to use

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solve transcendental equation in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202526/solve-transcendental-equation-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

No. In general, one equation in two unknowns has an infinite number of solutions. (Think of a contour plot. You are essentially looking for the level set, the locus of all points that yields zero for the dependent variable. It will be a curvilinear path in those variables.)

So you can't "solve" it. I would suggest a good solution to visualize the locus is indeed the function contour. ezplot will do it even better.